# K Nearest Neighbor Density Estimation

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

An intuitive way to estimate the pdf of a distribution $f$ is described [here](http://www.ssc.wisc.edu/~bhansen/718/NonParametrics10.pdf). Given a set of points you find the distance to the $k$th nearest neighbor for a point $x$ that we want to know the value of $f$ at. This allows us to calculate the volume of the sphere containing $k$ points. Approximating the probability mass within this sphere as $k$/(number of points in set), we can estimate $\hat{f}(x)$ as the probability mass over the volume.

This is fine, but there is a problem in more than dimension when the variance of the marginals  differs greatly. In this case, the volume of the sphere will depend very heavily on points in the dimension of greatest variance.

For example consider distribution $f(X)$ s.t $X \sim N(0,1)$. The estimation above should perform well given we have enough points. However now consider

$$g(x,y) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
         f(x) & \mbox{if $y = 0$}\\
        0 & \mbox{otherwise} \end{array} \right.$$

In this case we will be estimating the 'volume' by a circle, when in reality the distribution $g$ is only 1 dimensional which  ends up giving a very different answer to the estimation of $f$.

What is the most common way around this? Maybe perform the $k$ nearest neighbor in 2(+) dimensions and approximate the volume using ellipses?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your link has a side comment:

> When $X$ is multivariate the nearest neighbour ordering is not
>   invariant to data scaling. Before applying nearest neighbour methods,
>   it is therefore essential that the elements of $X$ be scaled so that they
>   are similar and comparable across elements.

and this is indeed the common practice, even though it makes interpretation more difficult.  The spheres in the standardised case do indeed correspond to ellipsoids in the original data.

A later statement on page 87 of your link

> Nearest neighbour methods are more typically used for regression than
>   for density estimation

and that may be because of difficulties in interpreting the kernel densities, while the regression often just works, and so has an empirical justification.